# How can I set layout alignment of the element in Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I add a TextView to stack object and I need move this element to the left side of the stack.
Also, I tried below code but the element did not move.

```
TextInput#text1
{
    position: absolute;
    left :0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this layout the `TextInput` will be at **left** side of `stack`

```
<Stack>
    <TextInput Id="Email" />
</Stack>
```

If you want to push the `TextInput` to the **right** you can do it like this:

```
<Stack>
    <Canvas></Canvas>
    <TextInput Id="Email" />
</Stack>
```

and

```
#Email
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

In this approach the `TextInput` will only use the last 100px and the empty `Canvas` will fill all the remaining empty space.